# Grouping daily by condition in Presto db

Tags: sql, presto

So I have  a table with the following  columns;
my_date (date),
username,
revenue,
department

I need help with an Sql query with date column, department column, and a count of user column where for every date  in the date column  we count ID between that date and the date in the date column  minus 90 days, where  users in this cohort is the sum of their revenue within the selected period is greater than 70

I was able to to implement it for a date I selected, however I am looking to implement it in a dashboard where every date filtered could give the output:

```
SELECT department, count(username) count_users, sum(revenu) rev FROM 
     (SELECT username,  department, sum(revenue) revenu 
                 FROM  my_table
                WHERE my_date BETWEEN (date('2023-12-30') - interval '89' DAY) AND date('2023-12-30')
                group by 1,2
                having sum(revenue)>=70

)GROUP BY 1
```

The above will produce 3 columns namely department, count_users, and   rev. However I will like it to calculate this for each date in the my_date column, such that I will get for columns my_date, department, count_users, and   rev in an efficient way

Comment: Could you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output ?